# How to Update UITableView With Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I'm trying to populate a table view from a SQlite database. Tickets get printed in the console, but nothings shows up on the table view. What's the proper way to update and refresh? Here is my code. Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import SQLite

class TicketTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var tickets = [String]()
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let dm = DatabaseManager.shared
        let db = dm.db!
        do {
            for row in try db.prepare(dm.tickets) {
                let ticket = row[dm.pick]
                tickets.append(ticket)
                debugPrint(ticket)
            }
            table.reloadData()
        } catch {}
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tickets.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ticket")!
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = tickets[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }     
}
```

Comment: Have you set the `delegate` and `datasource` of tableView? also check the outlet connection of table is connected with TicketTableViewController?

Comment: another problem is, to get you going move your code in viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear.  (in all cases, do not forget the super. ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic table views needs to know their delegate and datasource. If you didn't set the delegate and datasource, you can add them programmatically in your `viewDidLoad` function. Like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Set delegate and datasource
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self

        let dm = DatabaseManager.shared
        let db = dm.db!
        do {
            for row in try db.prepare(dm.tickets) {
                let ticket = row[dm.pick]
                tickets.append(ticket)
                debugPrint(ticket)
            }
            table.reloadData()
        } catch {}
    }
```